# Restful service call every moment in android

Tags: android, restful-architecture

I am working on application which updates UI every moment after getting data from web-service. I know we can call AsyncTask every-time to get data, but this look weird. There is also way of getting data in background service and receiving its broadcast in Activity. But again if there is no changes in database, we are using resources. Is there any way to check if changes occur in database then fetch data.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use push instead of pulling data every time. Implement a GCM push in your application. If there is any change in data you are interested in server sends a push about the change.

Then your application will receive the information about the change in broadcast receiver like you want to. Then your application can make the api call and fetch the actual data.

Here are more details about GCM :
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Comment: How would I do it, If I am concern with specific activity. If activity exists get data,either don't get.

Comment: Your activity can have dynamic broadcast receiver in your activity, register it in activity start. Now, if your activity is not there then you will not receive this broadcast and hence you will not make the API call.

Comment: To implement this you would need to change the server side implementation where you will have an api where you will share your push id and register for the change you are interested in, which is a very big architectural change. Sorry to say, for this sample code cannot be provided.